# When to post new answer vs overhaul edits

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, suggested-edits, link-only-answers

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28711128) where the [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28717304) was out of date because of several broken links and it was basically a link only answer.

[The answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982882) was originally a suggested edit to the existing upvoted question. That answer is now basically useless. My edit is essentially the same answer, with fresh links and more information. It was an overhaul of an edit, which I'm guessing was an issue.

My edit was rejected. Are overhaul edits frowned upon, even on old and upvoted answers?

Comment: Isn't the question off-topic in the first place, because it is asking us to find an off-site resource?

Comment: @honk, yes but it was on my google results and I hate to see a non closed question with no good answers

Comment: Then, shouldn't you better flag the question as off-topic instead of answering it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content.

If you want to provide your own answer, then post your own answer, don't edit someone else's answer to what you would have posted in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Are overhaul edits frowned upon, even on old and upvoted answers?

Yes.  An edit like that should be rejected as "clearly conflicts with author's intent".

Edits are for making the answer better, **not replacing the answer with a different one**. The upvotes and the check mark were for  the original answer, not your answer.

If you have an improvement to the answer, edit it.  If you have a *different* answer, post a new answer.

---

In this specific case, the original answer is "Here are a bunch of links to documentation."  Your answer is "Here is a link to and a summary of some *different* documentation."  Your answer is *entirely* different from the original answer; it links to different documentation and it actually includes the relevant content from that documentation.  Your answer is much better than the original answer, but that doesn't mean it should be an edit to the original answer.

Comment: it was an overhaul I don't see it as a different answer.

Comment: @Goose Please see my edit.